# Regex to find hex colors of #aabbcc format to shorten them to #abc

Tags: regex, hex

I need to match hex colors of format #aabbcc to be able to shorten them to #abc. Here are some examples:

- `#333333` - match
- `#666666` - match
- `#ff6666` - match
- `#ffaacc` - match
- `#d7d7d7` -
  does not match
- `#e5e5e5` - does not match

I've used this previously `/#([0-9A-Fa-f])(?:\1){5}/g` which matched first two, but I do need the third match as well. I'm stuck, please help :)

Comment: Try [`#[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}([0-9A-Fa-f])\1{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/qoRbpv/1). Or [`#([0-9A-Fa-f])\1([0-9A-Fa-f])\2{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/qoRbpv/2). Or [`#(?:ff([0-9A-Fa-f])\1{3}|([0-9A-Fa-f])\2{5})`](https://regex101.com/r/qoRbpv/3). What are your actual requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect! thanks a lot!

Comment: So, which one works as expected? Maybe, https://regex101.com/r/qoRbpv/4? `s.replace(/#([0-9A-Fa-f])\1([0-9A-Fa-f])\2([0-9A-Fa-f])\3/g, '#$1$2$3')`?

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51192533/3832970) with a JS demo, I suspect  you are using JS judging by the regex literal in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this last one is exactly what I was looking for! `#([0-9A-Fa-f])\1([0-9A-Fa-f])\2([0-9A-Fa-f])\3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want

```
/#([0-9a-f])\1([0-9a-f])\2([0-9a-f])\3/gi
```

and replace with `#$1$2$3`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qoRbpv/5).

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `([0-9a-f])` - Group 1: a hex char
- `\1` - a backreference to Group 1 value
- `([0-9a-f])\2` - Group 2 matching a hex char and a backreference to Group 2 value
- `([0-9a-f])\3` - Group 3 matching a hex char and a backreference to Group 3 value

Demo:

```js
var strs = ['#333333','#666666','#ff6666','#d7d7d7','#e5e5e5'];
var rx = /#([0-9a-f])\1([0-9a-f])\2([0-9a-f])\3/gi;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.replace(rx, '#$1$2$3'));
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: the back reference is in the expression to take into account the 2nd number of each duo, but to not include in the final substitution?

Comment: @TiagoVitorino Inline backreferences (those inside the pattern) are *consuming* patterns, so the text they match gets replaced.

Comment: @TiagoVitorino `\1`, `\2` and `\3` are *inline backreferenes*, they *match* the text that was *captured* by the corresponding capturing group. `#([0-9a-f])\1` when used against `#aa` matches `#`, then `a` (saved in Group 1) and then `\1` matches `a`. If the second letter is `b`, there won't be any match.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous solution matched **one** hex digit and then
**the same digit**, 5 times.

Now you should match also one hex digit, then the same **one** hex digit (group 1).
All this should be repeated 3 times, but with changing number of the
referred capturing group.

So you can use `/#([\dA-F])\1([\dA-F])\2([\dA-F])\3\b/gi`

Other changes to your solution:

- `\d` instead of `0-9`,
- `[A-Z]` with `i` option, so `a-z` is not needed.
- word boundary at the end, to "block" e.g. longer sequences of hex digits.
- non-capturing groups are not needed.